# How to use the parallel package inside another package, using devtools?

Tags: r, parallel-processing, devtools

When running the following code in an R terminal:

```
library(parallel)
func <- function(a,b,c) a+b+c

testfun <- function() {
    cl <- makeCluster(detectCores(), outfile="parlog.txt")    
    res <- clusterMap(cl, func, 1:10, 11:20, MoreArgs = list(c=1))
    print(res)
    stopCluster(cl)
}

testfun()
```

... it works just fine. However, when I copy the two function definitions into my own package, add a line `#' @import parallel`, do `dev_tools::load_all("mypackage")` on the R terminal and then call `testfun()`, I get an

```
Error in unserialize(node$con) (from myfile.r#7) :
error reading from connection
```

where #7 is the line containing the call to `clusterMap`.

So the **exact same code works on the terminal but not inside a package.**

If I take a look into `parlog.txt`, I see the following:

```
starting worker pid=7204 on localhost:11725 at 13:17:50.784
starting worker pid=4416 on localhost:11725 at 13:17:51.820
starting worker pid=10540 on localhost:11725 at 13:17:52.836
starting worker pid=9028 on localhost:11725 at 13:17:53.849
Error: (converted from warning) namespace 'mypackage' is not available and has been replaced
by .GlobalEnv when processing object ''
Error: (converted from warning) namespace 'mypackage' is not available and has been replaced
by .GlobalEnv when processing object ''
Error: (converted from warning) namespace 'mypackage' is not available and has been replaced
by .GlobalEnv when processing object ''
Error: (converted from warning) namespace 'mypackage' is not available and has been replaced
by .GlobalEnv when processing object ''
```

What's the root of this problem and how do I resolve it?

Note that I'm doing this with a completely fresh, naked package. (Created by `devtools::create`.) So no interactions with existing, possibly destructive code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While writing the question, I actually found the answer and am going to share it here.

The problem here is the combination of the packages `devtools` and `parallel`.

Apparently, for some reason, `parallel` requires the package `mypackage` to be installed into some local library, *even if you do not need to load it in the workers explicitly* (e.g. using `clusterEvalQ(cl, library(mypackage))` or something similar)!

I was employing the usual `devtools` workflow, meaning that I was working in `dev_mode()` all of the time. However, this led to my package being installed just in some special dev mode folders (I do not know exactly how this works internally). These are not searched by the worker processes invoked `parallel`, since they are not in dev_mode.

So here is my 'workaround':

```
## turn off dev mode
dev_mode() 
## install the package into a 'real' library
install("mypackage") 
library(mypackage)
## ... and now the following works:
mypackage:::testfun()
```

---

As [Hadley just pointed out](https://github.com/hadley/devtools/issues/571) correctly, another workaround would be to add a line

```
clusterEvalQ(cl, dev_mode())
```

right after cluster creation. That way, one can use the dev_mode.

Comment: Boy...I would really love it if devtools were fixed so that this didn't happen, seeing as how a lot of packages now use functions from the parallel package, and a lot of people would like to seamlessly use those packages within their packages without having to do this workaround.